# A good PDF view component for .net

Tags: pdf, controls, components

My application incorporates the manual as a PDF file and I want that the user can read the manual without exit and with a minimun overload.

Do you know any free (as in beer) component for .net that can just read pdf files? (I don't need editing).

Thank you.

P.D.: Yes, I did Googled, but I can't find a free one.

P.D.2.: If I don't need to install anything on the target computer, then it could be perfect!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85624/component-to-view-and-annotate-pdf-documents but no free ones :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit - Added**

You don't specify what you're using as a development language.  I'm guessing that it's some .Net language.  If not, this will NOT be helpful to you.

**End Added Content**

Is this a Windows Forms application?

I don't know if you've thought of this, but you can create a form with a WebBrowser control, and set the WebBrowser's DocumentSource to be the PDF document you're talking about.  This form can be controlled by your application.  The WebBrowser control will just use whatever version of Adobe Acrobat that  Internet Explorer would use on the client's PC.  Almost every computer out there has some version of the Acropbat Viewer, so there is very little chance you would need to install anything.

The reasons I recommend this are:

1. No need to buy a component
2. It works.  Simply, beautifully, and it's as error free as just opening the PDF via Internet Explorer.

Comment: David: I've tested your answer and works very well, is all that I need. Thank you.